# How to get second saturday of a month using shell/perl script?

Tags: perl, shell

Please provide me the scripting code to find out the second saturday in a month

Comment: Would you be so kind to show us your effort so far and where you got stuck? And please observe [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DateTime::Format::Natural`](https://p3rl.org/DateTime::Format::Natural) module, like this

```
$ echo 2nd saturday in april | perl -MDateTime::Format::Natural -E 'say DateTime::Format::Natural->new->parse_datetime(<>)->mdy'
```

#### output

```
04-09-2016
```

Or the module comes with a command-line tool `dateparse` which works like this

```
$ dateparse

dateparse> 2nd saturday in april
2016-04-09 00:00:00

dateparse> q

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Very  easy:

```
$ cal | sed -n '4s/^.* //gp'
12
```

This will print the day of the second Saturday in this month (March 2016). If you want the second Saturday of March 1959:

```
$ cal 3 1959 | sed -n '4s/^.* //gp'
14
```

If you want the First Saturday replace `4s` with `3s`, if you want the third Saturday use `5s`...

Comment: My cal (on Linux) has 2 trailing spaces in these lines, so your pipeline fails. Cut might be a more reliable option, and made to work for other days of the week as well.